# Plotting multiple files with common basename

Tags: python, matlab, plot, gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have 100 .txt files with two columns. The file names are file0, file1, file2, ..., file99. I want to plot all of them in one single graph. How can I do this in gnuplot or python or matlab or C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Example Python implementation using matplotlib

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delim = "," # Whatever delimiter your txt file uses
basename = "file"
numFiles = 100
plt.figure()
for i in range(numFiles):
    filename = basename + str(i) + ".txt"
    data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=delim)
    print data.shape
    plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be hard if you can read them in with Python, get them in a set of lists, and use a declarative plot package like Plotly.

Although Matplotlib is quick and easy, sometimes it takes more work than I imagine to do what seems obvious - especially with lots of data points that end up getting messy.

Answer (score 0):

In gnuplot:

```
plot for [n=0:99] "file".n with lp
```

Of course you can modify the plot command as needed (different styles, `using` directive, etc.).